# I, a UK citizen, part own a company in the EU. What happens after Brexit?

Tags: brexit

In 2017, I travelled to Greece where I co-founded a charity with a Greek citizen. I returned back to the UK in 2018 where I have been living since.

Does anybody have any information about what exactly my status would be as a Board Member of this charity when the UK leaves the EU? As I wouldn't have the right to work there any more could I be in the unusual case where I am unable to work or volunteer for a charity that I own?

I imagine this is one of the many grey areas that surround Brexit but I'd be interested to know if anything has been said on this matter.

Comment: Your question is probably a better fit for the [Law SE site](https://law.stackexchange.com/), since it's more focused on the post-Brexit legal situation rather than the [political process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of Brexit itself.

Comment: The situation is far from unusual; if I but one Google stock I would partially own Google yet that would not give me the right to live and work in the USA. That could be interesting would be if "being member of a board" and going to a meeting of the board is considered "work".